# AJAX with XMLHttpRequest doesn't send data

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to build a simple program using XMLHttpRequest to calculate the area of the triangle. I used this code for client-side;

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="txtLength">Length</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtLength" name="txtLength"><br><br>
        <label for="txtWidth">Width</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtWidth" name="txtWidth"><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
        <input type="button" name="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calArea();">
    </form><br><br>

    <div id="showArea">Enter Values and click Calculate.</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calArea() {
            var len = document.getElementById("txtLength").value;
            var wid = document.getElementById("txtWidth").value;
            var sub = 1;

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.readyState == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("showArea").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }
            };

            xhttp.open("POST", "calculate_area.php", true);
            xhttp.send(len&wid&sub);
        }

</script>
</body>
```

This code is for the server side.

```
<?php 

print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $len = $_POST['len'];
    $wid = $_POST['wid'];
    $area = (($len*$wid)/2);
    echo $area;
}   
else{
    echo "Not input detected.";
}

?>
```

Even tried so many codes, It doesn't send the data to server side.

Comment: You're sending the parameters as part of the URL, so they will be `$_GET` variables, I believe. What if you `var_dump($_GET);` ?

Comment: You're also separating them with multiple `?` - if you're going to send them as part of the URL, you need one `?` to separate the first parameter from the URL, and then separate the rest with `&`.

Comment: If you want them to be in `$_POST` you should send the parameters in the `xhttp.send()` argument.

Comment: BTW, it's the 2020's, and XMLHttpRequest is obsolete. You should use Fetch.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I never used this method and this is for my coursework. They request as it is. I changed the code and tried. It's not working yet. I don't know how to make it work. I need help to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I was sending the parameters as part of the URL, but need to send them as part of the request body.

Client-side code;

```
function calArea() {
    var len = document.getElementById("txtLength").value;
    var wid = document.getElementById("txtWidth").value;
    var sub = 1;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("showArea").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "calculate_area.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({len: len, wid: wid, sub: sub}));
}
```

Server-side code;

```
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $len = $_POST['len'];
    $wid = $_POST['wid'];
    $area = (($len*$wid)/2);
    echo $area;
}   
else{
    echo "Not input detected.";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put all the parameters into a string of the form `name=value` with each one separated by `&`. And the values should be encoded in case they contain special characters.

You also need to set the content type so this data will be parsed correctly.

So change

```
xhttp.send(len&wid&sub);
```

should be:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send(`len=${encodeURIComponent(len)}&wid=${encodeURIComponent(wid)}&sub=${encodeURIComponent(sub)}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> len&wid&sub
> ```

Taking some variables and putting the [Bitwise &](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) between them is not going to give you a useful value to submit to the server.

You need to encode the data in a format that you can transmit over HTTP and which your server-side code can read.

PHP supports URL Encoded and Multipart Form Encoded data natively so pick one of those.

The URLSearchParams API will generate URL Encoded data for you.

e.g.

```
xhttp.send(new URLSearchParams({ len, wid, sub }));
```

Passing a URLSearchParams object will also let XHR automatically set the correct Content-Type request header so PHP will know what it needs to do to decode the data and populate `$_POST` with it.